# Ionic: Focusing on input field on sub-header makes keyboard hide list-elements

Tags: ionic-framework, soft-keyboard, input-field

I'm working on an Ionic project and in one of our views we have an input field in the sub-header. Using this input field a user can search for other users which are displayed in an ion-list.

The problem I'm experiencing is that when the keyboard appears it's actually hiding part of the ion-list. After reading the Keyboard documentation from the Ionic docs, I believe the problem is caused because the sub-header input field and the ion-list are not part of the same scrollable area.

Is there any way I can solve this issue?

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-light bar-subheader item-input-inset">
    <div class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchUsers" ng-change="showUsersSuggestions($event);" ng-focus="enableSearch(true)" ng-blur="enableSearch(false)">
        <button class="button button-clear clear-search icon ion-ios-close-empty" ng-click="clearSearch()"></button>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-content>
    <ion-list can-swipe="true" ng-if="showSearchResults">
        <ion-item class="item item-divider list-result" style="border-top:0;">
            Search results
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="item item-avatar item-icon-right item-text-wrap list-result" ng-show="searchUsers && searchUsers.length >= 3 && usersSuggestions" ng-repeat="f in usersSuggestions">
            <img ng-src="{{getAvatarUrl(f)}}" width="40" height="40" ng-click="showProfileInfo(f)">
            <h2 ng-show="f.displayName" ng-click="showProfileInfo(f)">{{f.displayName}}</h2>
            <p ng-click="showProfileInfo(f)">{{f.email}}</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    ......
</ion-content>
```

Comment: did you solve this bro?

Answer (score 0):

The only way i found to solve this is to close the keyboard on content touch event..

```
<ion-content class="has-subheader" on-touch="hideKeyboard()">
    ...
</ion-content>

scope.hideKeyboard = function() {
    $cordovaKeyboard.close()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
</ion-content>

    <div keyboard-attach>
    </div>

</ion-view>
```

I just added this div with keyboard-attach. The ionic documentation says keyboard-attach works just with a footer but it worked for me. I tested on iOS9.